# Why there is not `package` type of thing by default in postgres like oracle have?

Tags: postgresql, package

Why postgres have not given  `package` like thing ,so that same type of function can be placed inside a individual collective unit . In current approach if postgres we have too write individual function that make to messy for origination of code.

Comment: You can sort of implement a poor man's package by chaining together multiple functions using "perform."  I actually wish Oracle would implement many of the things in PostgreSQL -- like array datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

There's a exhaustive discussion in PostgreSQL community about Oracle-style packages, as you can see [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo#Exotic_Features). I've been following this discussion from afar, IMHO there's a consensus that hackers should focus on more [significant issues](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAFj8pRBVb5kNLK8cAa7Q5YOs%3DoE9SdrPige%2Bi2DOa%3DfSQNMbQQ%40mail.gmail.com) - related to Oracle to PostgreSQL migration - than packages.

In short, there's the need but it's at the end of the queue.

Answer (score 0):

This subject has come up again and again since 2003. Every time the subject comes up, it is shot down in flames by the Postgres community.  Suggesting using schema and name space is equivalent to packages shows the lack of understanding of what a package does. A package is not just simply a collection of procedures. An Oracle package provides public and private access to procedures and variables within the package. An instantiated package is essentially a self contained object.

Answer (score -1):

There is Schema to classify function is needed.
If a schema name is included, then the function is created in the specified schema. Otherwise it is created in the current schema. The name of the new function must not match any existing function with the same input argument types in the same schema. However, functions of different argument types can share a name (this is called overloading).

Comment: Schema is different thing. Package is different.

Comment: Yes, but there is none package as the Oracle way in PostgreSQL.

Comment: I knew that , that is my question . why not package in postgres ? It is good practice .